# 16.04 - Battery not detected until plugged in via AC

Tags: 16.04, battery

I recently upgraded to 16.04, and since then I have been having a problem with my battery being detected.

When I turn on the laptop, the battery is not detected until I plug my laptop in with my AC charger. At that point, the battery is recognized, and I can unplug the AC charger and get information about my battery until my next reboot.

I have checked for information in `cat /sys/class/power_supply/` but `BAT0` is not present until I plug the laptop in.

I have a Dell Inspiron 7537.

How can I go about fixing this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some playing around, I finally managed to get my battery to be recognized by the system.

I took two steps, I am not sure if they are both required.

First I upgraded my kernel to version 4.5.3 by downloading the appropriate .deb files from:
http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/

I downloaded 3 files. The headers for my architecture, the header files for "all", and then the image for my architecture. I then installed them using `dpkg -i *.deb` in the folder I had downloaded them to.

I rebooted, and this still didn't work. I then added `acpi_osi=Linux acpi_rev_override` to `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` in `/etc/default/grub`.

I then ran `sudo update-grub`, restarted, and voila! I hope this helps someone.

Comment: I was using kernel 4.4 (vanilla from the OS no PPAs or special compilation) and only had to appy and extra `acpi_rev_override` as my `acpi_osi` alredy had `Linux`. Restarted and now my battery is recognised on first boot which means that TLP automatically selects battery saving mode rather than defaulting to AC mode. Hopefully this extends my battery life somewhat?


Frustrated that this needs to be one manually but happy that it is sorted as it was bugging me for a while.